# Hide and Show Child Tree elements whenever click in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg, svg-animate

I am trying to implement, some parent and childs as a tree. When I click parent element all it's childs should hide. when I click on same parent, all it's childs shoulds appear.

I am implemented but that is not working as expected because I am not good in JavaScript.

[[image: Output]]

It almost working. When I click on "React". It hiding parent also. It should hide only it's childs only.

```js
function place(id) {
  var gs = document.getElementsByTagName("g");
  // Hide all the elements
  for (var i = 0; i < gs.length; i++) {
    if (gs[i].id != "A") {
      if (gs[i].classList.contains("hidden")) {
        gs[i].classList.remove("hidden");
      } else {
        gs[i].classList.add("hidden");
      }
    }
  }
  // But make sure the one with "id" is visible
  document.getElementById(id).classList.remove("hidden");
}

function reset() {
  document.querySelectorAll("g").forEach(g => g.classList.remove("hidden"));
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="1250" height="1250">
       <rect x="0" y="0" width="1250" height="1250" style="fill:White;stroke:black;stroke-width:5" />
           <defs>
               <marker id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 15 15" refX="8" refY="8" markerWidth="10"markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
                   <path d="M 0 0 L 15 8 L 0 15 z" />
               </marker>           </defs>
   <g id="A" onclick="place('A')">
        <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" rx="10"></rect>
        <text x="150" y="125" alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="12" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" text-anchor="middle">Tech Stack</text>
   </g>
  
   <g id="AA" onclick="place('AA')">
        <rect x="250" y="150" width="100" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" rx="10"></rect>
        <text x="300" y="175" alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="12" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" text-anchor="middle">Frontend</text>
            <line x1="200" y1="125" x2="225" y2="125" stroke="black"/> 

    <line x1="225" y1="125" x2="225" y2="175" stroke="black"/>
          <line x1="225" y1="175" x2="245" y2="175" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
   </g>
    <g id="AAA"  onclick="place('AAA')" >
        <line x1="350" y1="175" x2="375" y2="175" stroke="black"/>
        <line x1="375" y1="175" x2="375" y2="225" stroke="black"/>
        <line x1="375" y1="225" x2="395" y2="225" stroke="black" marker-end="url(#arrow)" />
        <rect x="400" y="200" width="100" height="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="white" rx="10"></rect>
        <text x="450" y="225" alignment-baseline="middle" font-size="12" stroke-width="0.5" stroke="#000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" text-anchor="middle">React</text>
   </g>
        </svg>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="reset()">Reset circles</button>
```

Comment: you are missing SVG viewbox... (remark)

Answer (score 0):

i made a JSFiddle with a :
[example link](https://jsfiddle.net/6pnqx91v/4/)

but i explained some things about the code:

```
function searchGTags() {
  
  let tags = document.getElementsByTagName('g');

  Array.from(tags).forEach((tag, i) => {
    tag.n = i;
    tag.hiddenChilds = false;
    tag.onclick = () => {
      openCloseChilds(tag)
    };
  })
  gTags = tags;
}
```

with this function you will search for all  tags at the document , this will be in order , some g1 -> g2 -> g3 , be at the elements array position[0] , position[1](https://jsfiddle.net/6pnqx91v/4/) , position[3], then i add onclick function to all g elements, that will fire openCloseChilds function, also al g tags i added a prop .n that represent the hierarchy and another prop .hiddenChilds that represents if all descendants child's of this tags are hide or not.

```
function openCloseChilds(element) {
  if (!element.hiddenChilds) {
    hideChilds(element);
    element.hiddenChilds = true;
    return;
  }
  showChilds(element);
  element.hiddenChilds = false;
}
```

when you click in a g tag this function will check if their child's are hidden or not , if are hidden , will show again all their child's , if not are hidden it will hide all the child's.

this algorithm can be improved , but this is an easy way to solve this problem , peace my friend enjoy!

Comment: If I click , it hiding, but I click again same it not appearing back. how can I do

Comment: the example works as expected , check out the example link, if you click at react that is the last one child , it will not hide any parent , you have the code for this solution and the explanation of the code, this is the link of the example https://jsfiddle.net/6pnqx91v/4/